# Whats the efficient way to test if-elif-else conditions in python

Tags: python, if-statement, testing

I have bunch of python programs which needs to be assessed. The basic skeleton of the program contains a bunch of nested If-elif-else statements. I was wondering, on what could be the most efficient way to test (generate test cases) to test the program.

The following is a gist of the  program

```
if month == 1:
    if day <= 20:
        print("Capricorn")
    else:
        print("Aquarius")

elif month == 5:
    if day <= 21:
        print("Taurus")
    else:
        print("Gemini")
else:
    if day <= 21:
        print("Sagittarius")
    else:
        print("Capricorn")
```

It contains a lot more elif conditions. But I guess, you get the point. I was wondering,  on how do I generate test cases or test the code which covers all the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a problem like this with a lot of permutations and combinations, you should create a matrix of all<sup>1</sup> possible inputs and the expected outputs, then create a generalized test case that can iterate over all of the rows of the table.

Why a matrix? Because that is the easiest way to visualize this sort of scenario. If you have a collection of 24 distinct tests, for example, it will be hard for someone to quickly answer a question like "do you cover the case of February 29?". With all of the dates and expected values in a table it becomes trivial to answer such questions, and trivial to add additional test cases when the code changes.

For example, you'd start by creating a row for each month since your code seems to be based on a calendar. Then, for each month you would create rows for all of the important conditions -- first of the month, last of the month, special dates within the month (ie: if the 20th should give a different result than the 21st, etc).

Your table might conceptually look something like this:

```
| # month | day | sign
| 1       | 1   | capricorn
| 1       | 20  | capricorn
| 1       | 21  | aquarius
| 5       | 1   | taurus
| 5       | 21  | taurus
| 5       | 22  | gemini
```

... and so on. Then, write a test that can read each row, call the function, and compare the output to the expected result.

<sup>1</sup> By "all" I don't necessarily mean all. You need to define the normal cases and the edge cases, but you don't necessarily want to test every possible date.

Comment: How would test an if or else condition that does not produce an output or has a side-effect like return a value? So for ex: 

`if (cond = true) { do something; } else { do nothing; }`

How can we test the `nothing` case ?

Comment: @ChintanPathak: you can use the value `${NONE}` if you need to test that a function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 3):

Start writing tests, but include a coverage tool. You could install the [`coverage` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage) and use it directly, or use it together with a test runner like `nose` or `zope.testrunner`.

It'll tell you if your tests failed to exercise any lines of your code; after running your test a code coverage report gives you a coverage percentage and exact lines you missed.

You can even use additional tools like [duvet](http://pybee.org/duvet/) to visualise what lines you may have missed, or integrate with continuous integration tools like Jenkins or TeamCity to track coverage over time.

Comment: Coverage is good; simple to install and use with good reporting. If you need a test runner there is also the unittest module in the stdlib which works for simple cases.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making it table-driven:

```
testtable = {1: (20, "Capricorn", "Aquarius"),
             5: (21, "Taurus", "Gemini")}

def test(month, day):
    vals = testtable.get(month,
                         (21, "Sagittarius", "Capricorn"))  # default
    print( vals[1 + (day <= vals[0])] )

test(1, 20)  # --> Aquarius
test(1, 21)  # --> Capricorn
test(3, 21)  # --> Capricorn
test(3, 22)  # --> Sagittarius
test(5, 21)  # --> Gemini
test(5, 22)  # --> Taurus
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing is almost always based on providing input, and expecting output. But before you can implement tests, you need to specify the *interface* by which your code is used. Is it a library, providing an API? Then test the API, directly. That is, clearly define those functions or methods that external code will be calling, and then test these in the exact same way as external code would use them. Or is it a command line tool? Then test the command line behavior.

How to make sure that you test all the different code paths in your nested conditional structure? Think hard, and *evaluate*, using a [coverage analysis tool](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check astrological signs, you can use something like:

```
monthday = month * 100 + day
if monthday <= 120:
    print("Capricorn")
elif monthday <= 219:
    print("Aquarius")
and so on
```

Comment: This is a potential improvement to the code, but it doesn't answer the question about how to best test it.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools, such as [coverage.py](http://www.nedbatchelder.com/code/modules/coverage.html), to show you if your tests cases cover all your code.  However, when a program starts to have so many special cases, it is best to think about reorganizing it.

In this case, the way that the data is stored can make all the difference.  This does all the logic *with a single `if` statement*:

```
def classify(month, day):
    x = 100*month + day
    data = [(120, 218, "Aquarius"), (219, 320, 'Pisces'), (321, 419, "Aries"), (420, 520, "Taurus")]
    for start, end, sign in data:
        if start <= x <= end:
            return sign
```

Now that we have only one `if` statement to test, generating test cases becomes quite easy.

#### Details

The key above is getting the calendar date into a single number that can be easily be tested.  One could have chosen day-of-the-year.  I chose instead `100*month+day` because it is easy for humans to understand and check.

(The astrological data above is obviously incomplete.  Data for the rest of the dates and signs is [here](http://www.infoplease.com/ipa/A0202818.html).)

#### Quick How-to for Using `python-coverage`

The following will produce a nice interactive web page showing what statements were covered or not covered by your test script `test.py`:

```
python-coverage erase
python-coverage run test.py
python-coverage html "--omit=/usr/share/*"
firefox ./htmlcov/index.html
```

A sample of the html output:

[image]

This shows that coverage was 100%.

Comment: You've completely missed the point of the question, which is how to test the code.  For all we know, the astrological signs thing is just a toy example.  His real issue is how to write (or even better, to generate) tests for arbitrary code with lots of branches.

Comment: @JohnY OK.  Answer reworded.