# How to write if condition in python for testcase

Tags: python

```
script: |
      python3 -m coverage erase
      python3 -m coverage run -m pytest tests/ -v --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml --capture=${{ parameters.pytest_capture }}
      TEST_RESULT=$? # Create coverage report even if a test case failed
      python3 -m coverage html
      python3 -m coverage xml
      python3 -m coverage report --show-missing --fail-under=${{ parameters.covFailUnder }} && exit $TEST_RESULT
```

Here  in python3 -m coverage run -m pytest **tests**/ -v --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml --capture=${{ parameters.pytest_capture }}
tests are running from test folder, i need to make sure to check for both test and unittestcase folder.

so how do i write the script for reading both **tests** and **unittests **

I am struck in these, please provide the solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to

```
def test():
    result = your_function()
    if result == expected_result:
        print("Passed")
    else:
        print("Fail")
```

Also you may need to know maybe this was answered previously: [Whats the efficient way to test if-elif-else conditions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375408/whats-the-efficient-way-to-test-if-elif-else-conditions-in-python/28375674#28375674)

Answer (score 0):

To run tests from both tests/ and unittests/ folders, you can modify the script as follows:

```
python3 -m coverage erase
python3 -m coverage run -m pytest tests/ unittests/ -v --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml --capture=${{ parameters.pytest_capture }}
TEST_RESULT=$? # Create coverage report even if a test case failed
python3 -m coverage html
python3 -m coverage xml
python3 -m coverage report --show-missing --fail-under=${{ parameters.covFailUnder }} && exit $TEST_RESULT
```

Here, the argument tests/ unittests/ specifies that pytest should search for tests in both tests/ and unittests/ folders.